# How to do string substitution in expect?

Tags: expect

Say I have the following variable s:
`set s [lindex $argv 0]`

How can I make sure s does not contain any "-" characters?

So, basically I want to replace all occurrences of "-" in s with "".

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Expect uses Tcl syntax. Look at the [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm) command manual.

Comment: also take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.

Answer (score 1):

Use `set s [string map { - {} } [lindex $argv 0]]`

As pynexj says, details can be found at http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm#M34

Comment: Alternately: `set s [regsub -all -- {-} [lindex $argv 0] {}]` Here the double dash is required to separate the options from the pattern (since it starts with a dash).